# Is it possible to have a dynamic datasource in Tableau? I am using an API to get data

Tags: tableau-api, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I'm new to tableau. I want to build a tableau dashboard for analytics. The data I am fetching is basically scraped from another website. I will automate the website fetching process and then the scraping will be done. Can I modify the parameters of the website fetch(get) call to scrape different kinds of data according to filters on the website then feed it to tableau.